# Find/replace across workspace in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse Replace text in all Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376440/eclipse-replace-text-in-all-classes)

I want to replace all instances of Foo.bar() with Foo across all files in my workspace in eclipse. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Why has this been marked as a duplicate of a question that was asked over half a year later? If anything, [Eclipse replace text in all classes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3376440/983430) should be a duplicate of this, shouldn't it? Another duplicate: [Is there a way to find/replace across an entire project in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3426049/983430)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

When you do a text-based search in eclipse (using the flashlight button at the top of the screen and selecting the right tab) there's a `Replace...` button at the bottom of the dialog.  Press that, instead of search, and you can do a global find and replace.

Alternatively, you can use the refactoring feature to change it to something else.

Comment: Window - show view - search.. then ctrl+h, here we can replace all the text occurrences in workspace in a single click.