# Eclipse Replace text in all Classes?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a command to replace a string of code with another in all .java files in an Eclipse project?

In Visual Studio there is a "Replace in all files" option that I can't seem to find in Eclipse.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or look in the Search menu for Search>Search or Search>File depending on version. At bottom of dialog box, click Replace...  There you'll find the replace in files functionality.

Answer (score 14):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or look in the Search menu for Search>Search or Search>File Search Tab. At bottom of dialog box, click Replace

[image]

Comment: There's no replace button in 22022.03 version. Why on earth did they flip Crtl-F and Ctrl-H common use??

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the following option in Helios Version of Eclipse. Simply press CTRL+F you will get the "Find/Replace" Window on your screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about command but just 
press 'ctrl+h' the dialog that appears woulh have what you need

Answer (score 0):

Select the word and press  <kbd>alt+shift+r</kbd> then replace the word, it should reflect in all classes.