# how to rename multiple words within eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Say I have this list

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/3.jpg" alt="image03" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/4.jpg" alt="image04" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/5.jpg" alt="image05" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/6.jpg" alt="image06" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/7.jpg" alt="image07" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/8.jpg" alt="image08" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/9.jpg" alt="image09" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/10.jpg" alt="image10" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/11.jpg" alt="image11" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/12.jpg" alt="image12" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/13.jpg" alt="image13" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/14.jpg" alt="image14" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/15.jpg" alt="image15" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/16.jpg" alt="image16" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/17.jpg" alt="image17" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/18.jpg" alt="image18" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/19.jpg" alt="image19" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/20.jpg" alt="image20" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/21.jpg" alt="image21" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/22.jpg" alt="image22" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/23.jpg" alt="image23" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/24.jpg" alt="image24" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/25.jpg" alt="image25" /></a></li>
```

and I want to replace the word "large" in src="images/large/25.jpg" with the word "small" . How do I do this within the eclipse html file editor ? To manually change each and every word will be a tedious task.

There is a very similar feature to replace whole set of words(same word replaced by another word) in aptana but It seems to be missing in eclipse or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Replace text in all Classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376440/eclipse-replace-text-in-all-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Edit -> Find/Replace` menu option to bring up the generic `Find/Replace` dialog of eclipse for any text editor.

Comment: thank you..it worked:) ...when I right clicked on the word the edit option didn't came up so I was wondering where it might be...thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

Use Ctrl + F  in editor to replace the text value .

you can Ctrl + Shift + L in editor to see all shortcuts in eclipse.