# Replace all words in eclipse with variable

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project with many classes.

I wish to replace this command:

```
a.Dosomething();
```

by this one:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("click();", a);
```

(when a in the first command is the same in the second)

I read this answer: [Eclipse Replace text in all Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376440/eclipse-replace-text-in-all-classes)

But this is not possible with variable. There is a easy way to do it?

Comment: Which is the variable part? Use a regex with a capturing group to do the find/replace....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am getting your question right, you just want to replace all occurrences of `a.Dosomething();` with `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("click();", a);`.

You can try using "Search"-> "File..."-> Enter the text you want to in `Containing text:`

set the `File Name Pattern` to *******.

Set `Scope` to **Worskpace**

then hit `Replace...` you can enter your new text. You can also `Preview` all the places that will be affected. Finally hit `OK`.

Comment: I think `a` could also be `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor like Ultraedit, PSPAd, Notepad++ and look in the help for the replace feature of it. Usually it supports regular expressions...