# How to remove 1 line of code from all files

Tags: java, eclipse

I have `maven-java` project and it consists of 1000's of java files.
I have used `system.out.println("ncjscjddfhdefd")` for printing . I want to remove this line of code from all the files . I know manually doing would be very tough job so is it possible to remove this line of code from the project implementing 
 code (i.e from all files where i have used this line of code) ?

Using eclipse as an editor .

Comment: What are your thoughts of how to solve this? Have you tried anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3376455/342852

Comment: If on a unix-machine sed can be used: http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/04/sed-command-in-linux-delete-lines-from-file.html ("Delete lines containing a specific Pattern").

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd : Thanks . It worked for me .

Comment: Why would you use Java for this? There are way better tools.