# Is there a way to find/replace across an entire project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, project, replace

I'm trying to do a find and replace over many files within an Eclipse project, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Googling showed me that there are plug-ins that can accomplish this, but is there any built-in functionality in Eclipse? (It seems to be a pretty basic task; it's surprising me that I can't find a way to do it.)

Answer (score 279, accepted):

`Search->File` menu (also accessible using `Ctrl+H`, then navigate to `File` tab), enter the text to search for, hit the `Replace...` button which will give you another dialog where you can replace text.

Comment: strg/ctrl + h is the shortcut ;)

Comment: Does anyone know of a way to make searching across the current project the default when opening the search dialog? I constantly find myself opening the dialog, only to have to close it again, then go right-click on the project and do search from there (then make sure "selected resource" is selected in the dialog box).

Comment: @LihO it works fine. In File Search, enter the text in `containing text`. For `File name patterns` put "*", then hit `replace` and type in the text you want to replace with

Comment: got a Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The content of element type "property" must match "null".
 - Attribute "type" must be declared for element type

Comment: Take care when you are working with Subversion system which puts the repository in the same directory. **Do not forget to exclude** the repository from the replace process!

Comment: This can also be used with preserving the case of the replaced text (as described for the single file Search/Replace Ctrl+F in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61120051/14157403): Enable “Regular expression” in the search dialog as well as in the replace dialog and precede the replace string with “\C”.

Comment: After your replace you may see errors due to package import missing, to resolve that, select your project, go to source -> organize import, should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

it is a 2 step process, not 1 step as the norm.

> step 1. ctrl + H

> step 2.
> [image]

> step 3.
> [image]