# How to replace a String with another string in all files in eclipse project

Tags: eclipse

I want to change all files in project that contains below string

```
MainActivity.getResourceString(lang + "key" , abs)
```

to

```
getResource().getString(R.string.key)
```

How can I do it?

I should say that `"key"` and `abs` is variable string in each files.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800799/replace-string-in-all-files-in-eclipse) solution but I don't know how to do this problem by it.

Answer (score 0):

your solution link works.

If you need more :  http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-45.htm&cp=0_4_4_4_0