# How do I replace header and footer instantly in multiple web pages?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I'm setting up a new web app and came to know that the `company name` is spelled incorrectly in all the web pages. So, I want to `change` it in all of them. I am using `eclipse` `neon`.

Is there any way to add or replace text from all the web pages in `Eclipse` ? or Will I have to change them manually one by one?

Tried using `ctrl+shift+R` but it's for the change of method or variable name in eclipse.

Comment: In `IntelliJ IDEA` you can replace any text using `CTRL+SHIFT+R`. No Idea about eclipse IDE.

Comment: Don't know about Eclipse, but there are plenty of ways to do this, like `Replace in path` in IntelliJ, and replace in directory in Notepad++, and linux command to replace all recursively...

Comment: Maybe this might help you out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800799/replace-string-in-all-files-in-eclipse

Comment: On a side note for the future: resusable parts. You should have all your pages reused the same header and footer source! Then you make the change in only one place. Lookup "DRY code" :)

Comment: please try to show us your finding first.

Comment: @Zephyr Thanks. Probably best thing I have learned today.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eclipse IDE is mainly a programming tool, and as such it also supports:

- searching for files using wildcards
- replacing content using regular expressions within all finds matching your condition

Simply turn to *Search"->"File"* and enter your search text, a file pattern and then use *replace*!

And of course: the real answer is to step back and look into what you are doing! Such *repeating* information (that has to be always the same in many different places) should always come out of *1* source file, not out of 120 different files. That comment about "don't repeat yourself" is the real solution here!

Comment: Found another way .Search ->"Text"->"Workspace".  Right click on  selected text and replace all.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is better to create a separate header page and separate footer page and include them in all web page. So next time if you make this type of mistake you should not think about the all page, you can just change in one page and see the change in all page.

Comment: While I agree with this advice, it is not an answer to the question and should be a comment instead.

Comment: I agree with you. I have not enough  reputation to make a comment that’s why I though put it as an answer, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse - Search - File..

[image: search file]

in this example will be replace "conpany"  in all jsp's with 'company'

[image: replace]