# Replace javax.* package import statements with jakarta.* in all java files at once

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Since **javax.*** packages have been replaced with **Jakarta.*** packages in the latest release of spring 6 and hibernate I am facing a bit challenge to **replace all import statements** related to javax.* with Jakarta.* in all files(**1000s of java files**) at once. I am using the latest **eclipse IDE** and have **ubuntu OS**. Right now I am replacing it manually by opening one java file at a time. Is there a way to do this at once for all files?

Comment: have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800799/replace-string-in-all-files-in-eclipse

Comment: If only there were a "Replace all" kind of functionality in the IDE....

Comment: You can do the SED approach. However, it also requires to carefully review and check libraries used in your app. All libs need to support jakarta namespace ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Eclipse Transformer tool available from the Apache TomEE project here:

https://tomee.apache.org/latest/docs/jakartaee-9/eclipse-transformer.html

> *"The Eclipse Transformer provides translation from `javax` to `jakarta` on various artifacts, including Java source source, compiled Java classes, along with jar, war and ear files."*

The README page contains instructions for building the transformer tool and documentation on how to use it.

Another alternative would be use Eclipse's search / replace across your entire codebase; see [Replace String in all files in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800799).  However that is potentially risky; e.g. because of the possibility of making mistakes in the patterns that you use.

Answer (score -4):

ctr+shift+o

I think this will work.