# How to find/replace using regular expressions in ecilpse?

Tags: java, regex

Hi i have to replace at least 100 instances of a string in a single code.
The string i want to replace is

`Music2.playGeneric2(context, R.raw.try_again);//text after R.raw.* could be anything`

or
  `Music2.playGeneric2(context, R.raw.tryagain);`

with

`Music2.playGeneric2(context, "try_again.mp3");`
and 
   `Music2.playGeneric2(context, "tryagain.mp3");`

I have found a lot for this but could not create a regular expression as i am new to it, hope to get some help....Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this question: [Is there a way to find/replace across an entire project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426049/is-there-a-way-to-find-replace-across-an-entire-project-in-eclipse)

search --> file
you can use a regex to search and there's a replace option.

as for a regexp that would capture your methods, you could try:

```
Music2.playGeneric2\(context, R\.raw\.([^)]*)\)(.*)
```

that would set the 2nd argument (technically everything after the 1st argument up to the close-bracket as the 1st capture group, and the rest of the line as the 2nd capture group.

you could then replace with something like:

```
Music2.playGeneric2(context, "$1")$2
```

to quote the 2nd argument

Comment: I want to find and replace particular strings in a file...dont want to search a file..

Comment: @Sydroid - it searches for text inside files.

Comment: hey nice, now i want to replace "R.raw." to a"/""(double quotation mark) and "");" to ".mp3);" How should i do this

Comment: Hey its working Find : Music2.playGeneric2\(context, R\.raw\.([^)]*)\)(.*)
Replace : Music2.playGeneric2(context, "$1.mp3")$2  but not for 2 underscore for eg: try_again_01