# Replace without modifying case in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, search, replace, find, case

I want to be able to run a search and replace where it ignores the case of the found items, but it doesn't change the case of any of the letters in them either. Basically, if I want to search and replace 'red' with 'blue', the following should happen;

```
red -> blue
Red -> Blue
RED -> BLUE
reD -> bluE
```

And so on.

Comment: It may be achieved by writing a small Java program. In Java regex you can catch the matched group. Thus we can identify the letters and the case's of these letters. BUT IMHO it is difficult to do this using Eclipse "Find and Replace" dialog. If you are expecting such program then update your post with exact need i.e if the matched group has all lower case letter then the replacement should be in lower case letters. If the matched group has ALL upper case letters then the replace group should be in upper case letters etc etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the first three cases using eclipse regex replace pattern \C.

Anything following the \C pattern will take on the casing of the replaced string (all lower case, capitalized, all upper case).

`red -> \Cblue` will give the following

```
red -> blue
rEd -> blue
reD -> blue
Red -> Blue
RED -> BLUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use emacs.  It does that automatically (except for the last case, which is unusual).

Comment: Just installed it, how would I accomplish this specific functionality?