# Search and replace regex in eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

I have some kind of different strings in various files like

```
"a.x"
"a.y"
```

in a project in eclipse. Where `"a.` is common between all. 
I'm wondering is possible to search for 
`"a.*"` and replace with `a.*`

So basically it becomes

Before

```
"a.x"
"a.y"
```

After

```
a.x
a.y
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: @Biffen: It's not a regex understanding, it's a question about how find/replace works in Eclipse and it's support of regex

Comment: If you have any regex that you have attempted so far, please add it to the question. It will help reduce the downvoting you are getting. Although I think the question is fine as it is

Comment: Use Search File for this see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3426049/2670892). Select Regular Expression on both dialogs.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the capture groups, I believe in Eclipse you can use `$1` for the first capture group. So this should work:

Search: `"a\.(.+)"`

Replace: `a.$1`