# Remove if statement and curly braces but keep contents

Tags: java, regex

I have a logger class with an `isDebugEnabled()` method. This is duplicated over 16,000 times so we now check if it is enabled in the method itself as opposed to everywhere in the project.

```
        if ( logger.isDebugEnabled() ) 
    {
        logger.logMethodEntryMessage();
    }
```

I want to remove the if statement but keep the `logger.logMethodEntryMessage();` everywhere in the project. Is it possible to use Notepad++ and regex or eclipse and regex to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's the same if statement everywhere?

Comment: @ctwheels pretty much, some invoke a different logger method but they are all the same format.

Comment: @DeaneKane it's important for you to give us more specifics on it. Because based on the information here [this](https://regex101.com/r/5vKAkm/1) `(?:if\s*\(\s*logger.isDebugEnabled\(\)\s*\)\s*{\s*|\G(?!\A))(?:(logger.logMethodEntryMessage\(\)\s*;)|\s*})` works, but if it's a different method, it won't.

Comment: @tobias_k No I am not looking for Java code to do the replacement. Just code I am replacing written in Java.

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks, if I replace that method with another method it should work? I only have about 3 different methods. `logMethodExitMessage();` My `logger.debug( ("fileType: " + fileType) );` method takes various parameters though.

Comment: @DeaneKane yes [this](https://regex101.com/r/5vKAkm/2): `(?:if\s*\(\s*logger.isDebugEnabled\(\)\s*\)\s*{\s*)(logger.logMethodEntryMessage\(\)\s*;)\s*\}` works in Notepad++. You can change the method easily this way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202816/discussion-between-deane-kane-and-ctwheels).

Answer (score -1):

I believe a simple search and replace should work, `Ctrl+R` in Intellij or `Ctrl+F` in Eclipse. Here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426049/is-there-a-way-to-find-replace-across-an-entire-project-in-eclipse).

Comment: It's not simple because he wants to remove the if statement and the curly braces and leave just the "logger.logMethodEntryMessage();"

Comment: Why not replace the entire thing with `logger.logMethodEntryMessage()` ? Sounds simpler to me.

Comment: Never even thought about that @w1sh