# Eclipse : Does multiple workspace decrease the speed/performance of the eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, performance, workspace

I'm working  on multiple projects and i find little messy to keep all the projects in one workspace. I was wondering if creating multiple workspace reduces the speed and performance of the eclipse . I already have 2 workspaces , is it advisable to create multiple workspaces?. I tried looking up on the internet, could not find a straight forward answer. It will really helpful if some could give some insight on this . 
Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Vin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating multiple workspace won't decrease Eclipse performance, and will actually have a *positive* impact on feature like search, which you can limit to a workspace (as in "[Find/replace across workspace in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876664/find-replace-across-workspace-in-eclipse)").
Keeping every projects under the sun in *one* workspace could actually lead to performance issue (as this [old bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=35974) illustrated at the very beginning of Eclipse).

I usually create at least two, when I need to work on the same project (same name) but versioned in two different branches i the Version Control System tool that I use: you cannot open two Eclipse project with the same name in *one* Eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that has helped me is creating a new workspace every once in a while and import the existing projects from the older workspace. what really kills eclipse performance over a period of time is the history that eclipse keeps building up for files in your workspace. Creating new workspace and importing all projects from the old one helps getting rid of those historical files.